# TabHost Clic on the selected tab

Tags: android

I have a tabhost with 5 tabs, and the content of each one is an ActivityGroup than can start different activities. I'm trying to redefine the clic on the selected tab of my tabHost, to go back on the main activity of this tab.

For example, I'm in the first tab, which has a list of item. If I select one item, it replaces the content of my current tab with the new activity. And then, I want to clic on my selected tab in my TabBar, to go back to the previous activity.

My problem is to detect a clic on the selected tab, I cannot use the OnTabChangeListener, because it's not a tabChanged, and I don't find any other way ...

Thanks

Comment: what is the behaviour of the back key in this precise case?

Comment: Exactly the same, but this tab clic behaviour would be usefull when there were 3 or 4 activities launched in the same tab. It's just to avoid the 3 or 4 clics on the back key. It would be a sort of home button for each tab, like the logo on website.